# No visible interface for UICollectionView declares the selector indexPathForSelectedRow

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to change the code I had on a Table View Controller to a Collection View Controller, right now I'm trying to get the Segue to work but I get this error:

> No visible @interface for 'UICollectionView' declares the selector 'indexPathForSelectedRow'

This is my Segue:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showUpcomingRelease"]){
        UpcomingReleaseViewController *upcomingReleaseViewController = (UpcomingReleaseViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        upcomingReleaseViewController.singleRelease = [self.upcomingReleases objectAtIndex:[[self.collectionView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showUpcomingRelease"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];
        UpcomingReleaseViewController *upcomingReleaseViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        upcomingReleaseViewController.singleRelease = self.upcomingReleases[selectedIndexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `indexPathsForSelectedItems` in place of `indexPathsForSelectedRow`. 
But this instruction will return more than one indexPath if you select more than one item. You should restrict the selection to one item by setting the `allowsMultipleSelection` of the UICollectionView to `NO`.

That said, Xcode has a brilliant autocompletion feature, you could have started to type "`index`" and it would have shown `indexPathsForSelectedItems` directly, you can also refer to the excellent [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) provided with Xcode. I Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thank you I found the answer with your help.

Answer (score -2):

From documentation, 2sec google research :

```
– indexPathsForSelectedItems
```